# Imacros problems in twitter

Tags: twitter, imacros, twitter-follow

I'm running a macro with Imacro to do mass follow on Twitter.

The macro does not seem to work anymore.

**Here is the results :**

```
RuntimeError: element BUTTON specified by TXT:Suivre<SP>AbonnÈ<SP>Se<SP>dÈsabonner<SP>BloquÈ<SP>DÈbloquer* was not found, line: 1
```

What should I do ?

Comment: Change your Macro to find the button (if still exists).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `TYPE=SPAN` like that

```
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Abonné<SP>Se<SP>désabonner<SP>Bloqué<SP>Débloquer<SP>En<SP>attente<SP>Annuler
```

and not `TYPE=BUTTON`